# Why do I get "andothers" rather than "et al." using the authoryear citation style?

Tags: biblatex

I am struggling with this problem of getting "andothers", and not "et al."... Does someone know where it comes from?

Here is a bit of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

% formatting of hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
% Use biblatex for references - change style= as appropriate
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,maxnames=99,style=authoryear,bibstyle=nature, url=false, doi=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
% add your references to this file
\addbibresource{test.bib} 

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEverycitekey{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{day}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}

\begin{filecontents}{\test.bib}
@article{nardo_competition_2016,
    title = {Competition between Visual Events Modulates the Influence of Salience during Free-Viewing of Naturalistic Videos},
    volume = {10},
    issn = {1662-5161},
    url = {http://journal.frontiersin.org/Article/10.3389/fnhum.2016.00320/abstract},
    doi = {10.3389/fnhum.2016.00320},
    abstract = {},
    journaltitle = {Frontiers in Human Neuroscience},
    shortjournal = {Front. Hum. Neurosci.},
    author = {Nardo, Davide and Console, Paola and Reverberi, Carlo and Macaluso, Emiliano},
    urldate = {2022-01-31},
    date = {2016-06-28},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Nardo et al. - 2016 - Competition between Visual Events Modulates the In.pdf:C\:\\Users\\USER\\Zotero\\storage\\ARJR8KBX\\Nardo et al. - 2016 - Competition between Visual Events Modulates the In.pdf:application/pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't actually reproduce the issue with your example code, but the following MWE should show the issue you are asking about

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın andothers 2006]

The problem is that you load `babel` without passing a document language on to `babel`. `babel` will fall back to the dummy language `nil` and `biblatex` does not have any language definitions for `nil`. Hence the warnings

```
Package biblatex Warning: Language 'nil' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using dummy definitions on input line 10.


Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'andothers' untranslated
(biblatex)                at entry 'aksin' on input line 11.
```

The solution is to

- either not use `babel` if you don't want to use it
- or pass your document language to `babel` (this can be done by passing the language as global class option or by passing it to the package directly via `\usepackage`).

I think I generally prefer the second solution. With the language passed to `babel` (in the example as global class option) things will look as intended.

```
\documentclass[12pt, english]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın et al. 2006]

See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1211.

Comment: You second MWE looks the same as the first, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Marijn `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` vs `\documentclass[12pt, english]{article}`. The point is that you need to tell `babel` about the document language.

Comment: Ah yes I see it now, I was expecting the language to be added in `\usepackage{babel}` but adding it in the documentclass may be better because it can propagate to other packages as well if needed.

Comment: OK thank you all, it worked perfectly...