# Bibliography output "andothers"

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am trying to understand where this weird output format comes from. Why `andothers` is one word and also in bold? What about the month with the first letter being lowercase? Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia, csquotes}
\usepackage{chemmacros}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\string~/Dropbox/tex/common.bib}
```

and here is the bibentry:

```
 @article{li10,
   1 author={Olivecrona, Marcus and Blaschke, Thomas and Engkvist, Ola and Chen, Hongming},
   2 title={Molecular de-novo design through deep reinforcement learning},
   3 journal={Journal of Cheminformatics},
   4 year={2017},
   5 month={9},
   6 volume={9},
   7 number={1},
   8 pages={48},
   9 issn={1758-2946},
  10 doi={10.1186/s13321-017-0235-x},
  11 url={https://doi.org/10.1186/s13321-017-0235-x}
  12 }
```

[image]

Comment: You've loaded `polyglossia` but set no language to the document, `biblatex` cannot know the language in this case and prints the internal strings names in bold. And you probably get some warnings there too. So, set a language to the document.

Comment: If you can write it as an answer then I would accept it as it solves the problem.

Comment: A duplicate of: [Why do I get "andothers" rather than "et al." using the authoryear citation style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641211/why-do-i-get-andothers-rather-than-et-al-using-the-authoryear-citation-styl)